# Check if a record from database exist in a csv file

Tags: mysql, database, python-3.x, csv, database-design

today I come to you for inspiration or maybe ideas how to solve a task not killing my laptop with massive and repetitive code.

I have a CSV file with around 10k records. I also have a database with respective records in it. I have four fields inside both of these structures: *destination*, *countryCode*,*prefix* and *cost*

Every time I update a database with this .csv file I have to check if the record with given *destination*, *countryCode* and *prefix* exist and if so, I have to update the *cost*. That is pretty easy and it works fine.

But here comes the tricky part: there is a possibility that the *destination* may be deleted from one .csv file to another and I need to be aware of that and delete that unused record from the database. What is the most efficient way of handling that kind of situation?

I really wouldn't want to check every record from the database with every row in a .csv file: that sounds like a very bad idea.
I was thinking about some time_stamp or just a bool variable which will tell me if the record was modified during the last update of the DB BUT: there is also a chance that neither of params within the record change, thus: no need to touch that record and mark it as modified.

For that task, I use Python 3 and mysql.connector lib.

Any ideas and advice will be appreciated :)

Comment: I do not understand how you know that one destination is deleted on the .csv file. You have a line on the csv file that tells you that the line has to be delete ?

Comment: No. You just have ie. version from March which will consist a destination ie. Spain and in version from April this destination has been deleted (but there is no information about it given explicitly )

Comment: Ok, so basically whatever entry that is not in the csv file must be deleted  from the DB, every entry that is in the csv file must be updated in the DB. 
For me that sound pretty obvious then ; you first update the DB with the entries of the csv file. Doing so you append in a local list  every entries that has been updated. Than you can delete all the entries not matching that local list. 
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're keeping a time stamp why do you care if it's updated even if nothing was changed in the record? If the reason is that you want to save the date of the latest update you can add another column saving a time stamp of the last time the record appeared in the csv and afterwords delete all the records that the value of this column in them is smaller than the date of the last csv.

Answer (score 0):

If the .CSV is a *replacement* for the existing table:

```
CREATE TABLE new LIKE real;
load the .csv into `new`  (Probably use LOAD DATA...)
RENAME TABLE real TO old, new TO real;
DROP TABLE old;
```

If you have good reason to keep the old table and patch it, then...

1. load the .csv into a table
2. add suitable indexes
3. do *one* SQL to do deletes (no loop needed).  It is probably a multi-table `DELETE`.
4. do *one* sql to update the prices (no loop needed).  It is probably a multi-table `UPDATE`.

You can probably do the entire task (either way) without touching Python.